# Flutter: Matrix4 to rotate a Container by its center?

Tags: math, flutter

I have an `AnimatedContainer`, and I want to rotate it by 180 degrees, and the origin should be at its center.

It has a `transform` parameter that, unfortunately, asks for a `Matrix4`.

There is no explanation of `Matrix4` in the Flutter documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4-class.html

What is the Matrix4 I must use to rotate it by its center?

Comment: Found Matrix4 explanation here, but still don't get it! https://medium.com/flutter-community/advanced-flutter-matrix4-and-perspective-transformations-a79404a0d828

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found the answer and just made this package (to do all kinds of transformations, not only rotate by the center): https://pub.dev/packages/matrix4_transform

```
var height = 30;
var width = 30;

AnimatedContainer(
   color: Colors.red, 
   width: width, 
   height: height,
   transform:
     Matrix4Transform()
       .rotateDegrees(180, origin: Offset(width/2, height/2))
       .matrix4,
);
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much for posting this, you saved my *ss!

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to use a `Matrix4` for a simple 180 degrees rotation. Use `RotationTransition` to wrap your `AnimatedContainer` instead. `RotationTransition` takes a `turns` parameter, which is an `Animation<T>` whose value can be used to represent the `RotationTransition`'s child widget rotation in radians. This way, you can control your rotation animation via an `AnimationController`. Check out [this example from the Flutter official GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/layers/widgets/spinning_square.dart) to find out more.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no AnimationController, and I don't intend on having one. An AnimatedContainer needs no AnimationController, needs no vsync. It's much easier to use. If only I could understand Matrix4.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the alignment using the `transformAlignment` field.

```
AnimatedContainer(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(_yourAngle),
  transformAlignment: Alignment.center,
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Comment: Good info! I think this parameter is new, it did not exist when I asked the question.